# Fullcalendar crashes when switching views

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using Fullcalendar.js in my rails app (through fullcalendar gem https://github.com/mkhairi/fullcalendar).

The version of fullcalendar.js I have is 3.8.2 (I find this in the inspector in chrome by typing Fullcalendar in the console and I get this)

> Fullcalendar
>   {version: "3.8.2", internalApiVersion: 12, applyAll: ƒ, debounce: ƒ, isInt: ƒ, …}

When I do the following steps Fullcalendar crashes, and doesn't render the view:

1- initial view is week view (agendaWeek)

2- changing day view by for instance picking a day the next week (d = today + 1 week)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',d);
```

3- changing the view back to day view (agendaDay)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView','agendaDay');
```

4- changing view to week view

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView','agendaWeek');
```

It gives the following error, and doesn't load the week view:

```
fullcalendar.self- 
4ac7cb5378baf9f7c517f032032aaab305cd3b2213aacbab690c4efdc0047f46.js? 
 body=1:11974 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'minTime' of 
null
at ResourceTimeGrid.TimeGrid.computeTimeTop (fullcalendar.self- 

4ac7cb5378baf9f7c517f032032aaab305cd3b2213aacbab690c4efdc0047f46.js? 
body=1:11974)
at ResourceTimeGrid.TimeGrid.computeDateTop (fullcalendar.self- 
4ac7cb5378baf9f7c517f032032aaab305cd3b2213aacbab690c4efdc0047f46.js? 
body=1:11968)
at ResourceTimeGrid.TimeGrid.computeSegVerticals (fullcalendar.self- 
4ac7cb5378baf9f7c517f032032aaab305cd3b2213aacbab690c4efdc0047f46.js? 
body=1:12007)
at ResourceTimeGrid.TimeGrid.updateSegVerticals (fullcalendar.self- 
4ac7cb5378baf9f7c517f032032aaab305cd3b2213aacbab690c4efdc0047f46.js? 
body=1:11995)
at TimeGridFillRenderer.attachSegEls (fullcalendar.self- 
4ac7cb5378baf9f7c517f032032aaab305cd3b2213aacbab690c4efdc0047f46.js? 
body=1:14104)
at TimeGridFillRenderer.FillRenderer.renderSegs (fullcalendar.self- 
4ac7cb5378baf9f7c517f032032aaab305cd3b2213aacbab690c4efdc0047f46.js? 
body=1:6435)
at TimeGridEventRenderer.EventRenderer.renderBgSegs 
(fullcalendar.self- 
4ac7cb5378baf9f7c517f032032aaab305cd3b2213aacbab690c4efdc0047f46.js? 
body=1:4321)
at TimeGridEventRenderer.EventRenderer.renderBgRanges 
(fullcalendar.self- 
4ac7cb5378baf9f7c517f032032aaab305cd3b2213aacbab690c4efdc0047f46.js? 
body=1:4297)
at TimeGridEventRenderer.EventRenderer.render (fullcalendar.self- 
4ac7cb5378baf9f7c517f032032aaab305cd3b2213aacbab690c4efdc0047f46.js? 
body=1:4273)
at ResourceTimeGrid.DateComponent.executeEventRender 
(fullcalendar.self- 
4ac7cb5378baf9f7c517f032032aaab305cd3b2213aacbab690c4efdc0047f46.js? 
body=1:8848)
```

Here is a snippet of the code I m using:

```
$('#calendar').each(function(){
var calendar = $(this);
calendar.fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: true,
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true,
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  locale: 'fr',
  slotDuration: '00:15:00',
  nowIndicator:true,
  defaultDate:"2019-01-14",
  displayEventTime: false,
  hiddenDays:[0],
  minTime:'06:00',
  maxTime:'23:00',
  columnHeaderFormat:"ddd D",
  views : 
  {
    month:
    {
      groupByResource:true,
    },
    agenda:
    {
      groupByDateAndResource:true,
    },
    day:
    {
      groupByDateAndResource:true,
    },
  },
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    alert("dayClick");
  },
  viewRender: function(view, element) {
    console.log(view.options);
  }
  //...other callbacks, not necessary to paste them
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As far as I can see, the code you've posted doesn't reproduce the issue. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yk52Lu9c/1/  . The most likely reason for the error you're getting is that you didn't specify a valid value for `minTime`. But, as per your code, you did do that. Perhaps there's some problem specific to the Ruby implementation...but it's hard to see what that could be, since fullCalendar is purely JavaScript, client-side code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just posted the fix to my problem with my explanation below.

Answer (score 2):

Found it! (at least a workaround)

When I'm doing:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',d);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView','agendaDay');
```

I'm actually switching view before all the events are fetched, which seems to be a known issue with fullcalendar

Here is the link:

switching views before event fetch resolves, JS error #3689
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3689

Which means that the fix is to wait for all the event to be fetched before changing the view, for instance with:

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',d);
  $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView','agendaDay');
  });
```

Works just fine for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Out of interest, these lines `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',d);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView','agendaDay');` ...do you run them immediately after your declare your calendar? If so, why not just set those values as the defaults for the calendar in the first place? Then you wouldn't need this extra code.

Comment: Actually I'm calling them after the calendar declaration, inside a jquery date picker callback, for instance when a user selects a day. That's the reason why I cannot do it in the first place.

Comment: Ah ok that makes more sense